# How to specify required harmony arguments in package.json?

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6

I'm going to use [destructuring assignments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) in a cli Node.js application and thus I need to run `node` with `--harmony_destructuring` argument.

Is there any way to specify required harmony arguments in `bin` section of `package.json`?

Comment: I guess that by `config.json` you mean `package.json`, right?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I mean `package.json`. Corrected the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include the arguments inside the executable file itself:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node --harmony_destructuring
...
```